# Reading a gzipped file with JSON data for thousands of users

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, json, compression

I'm a newbie in Python.

I need to read a GZ file contains thousands of users. 
But I think my code is not optimized in this case. Could anyone can help me? What should I do to improve performance? Or is it standard?

```
if os.path.isfile("file.gz"):
    with gzip.GzipFile("file.gz", 'r') as fin:   
        for line in fin:
            if get_new_user is True:
                if datetime.strptime(json.loads(line).get('UpdatedAt'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').date() == (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date():
                    users.append(json.loads(line))
            else:
                users.append(json.loads(line))    
    os.remove("file.gz")
    return users
```

Comment: Could you include an excerpt of the un-gzipped data?

Comment: What is `get_new_user`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your code is somewhat non-optimal.

1. In the case `get_new_user is True`, you call `json.loads(line)` once for the "UpdatedAt" test, and if that passes, you call it *again*, returning effectively the same value, to append the users list.
2. In the case of `get_new_user is True`, you call `(datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date()` once for each user, yet it is effectively constant.  You should move this out of the loop.

You could refactor your code like this:

```
threshold = (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date()
for line in fin:
    user = json.loads(line)
    if get_new_user is True:
        if datetime.strptime(user.get('UpdatedAt'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').date() == threshold:
            users.append(user)
    else:
        users.append(user)
```

You are doing the `get_new_user is True` test for each user/line in the file.  That too is constant, and only needs to be done once.  It is a tiny gain, but you could put the `for` loop inside the `if` and `else` clauses.

```
if get_new_user is True:
    threshold = (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date()
    for line in fin:
        user = json.loads(line)
        if datetime.strptime(user.get('UpdatedAt'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').date() == threshold:
            users.append(user)
else:
    for line in fin:
        users.append(json.loads(line))
```

And maybe using some list comprehensions and a generator expression for fun ...

```
if get_new_user is True:
    threshold = (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date()
    users = [ user for user in (json.loads(line) for line in fin)
              if datetime.strptime(user.get('UpdatedAt'),
                                   '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
                                  ).date() == threshold ]
else:
    users = [ json.loads(line) for line in fin ]
```

Or if you are truly brave ... almost a 1-liner:

```
threshold = (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date()
users = [ user for user in (json.loads(line) for line in fin)
          if get_new_user is not True or
             datetime.strptime(user.get('UpdatedAt'),
                               '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
                              ).date() == threshold ]
```

---

I've left your `if get_new_user is True:` statement alone, but it is a little non-Pythonic.  Usually, you'd just use `if get_new_user:`, but those two statements are very different.  The first is true **if and only if** `get_new_user` is `True` whereas the second would be true when `get_new_user` contains any non-falsey value, such as: `True`, or `"True"` or `1`, or `17` or `"False"`, or `[0]`, ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break-down your existing code:

```
if os.path.isfile("file.gz"):
    with gzip.GzipFile("file.gz", 'r') as fin:   
        for line in fin:
```

The above code would work faster if you made this into a separate function and loaded the file fully first (perform all the I/O in a single operation, loading the data into the memory (much faster), rather than keeping the loop as incrementing the file pointer to read the next line). I/O is slow, always try to get files into a memory structure before doing anything.

```
            if get_new_user is True:
```

This line would be evaluated every single time the loop runs. We should avoid that.

```
                if datetime.strptime(json.loads(line).get('UpdatedAt'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').date() == (datetime.today()-timedelta(1)).date():
```

This line executes datetime.today() every single time the loop hits this line. Again, something to avoid by placing the operation result into a variable, before the loop runs.

```
                    users.append(json.loads(line))
            else:
                users.append(json.loads(line))
```

This is the same line - both sides of the if statement run this exact statement regardless of the result of the date check - meaning the date check is kind of useless - **AND** the load operation is duplicated/can be separated, right? Perhaps you are missing a line of code? perhaps this is a logic error? It would be helpful to get a comment regarding this.

```
    os.remove("file.gz")
    return users
```

you miss the initial declaration of the users data type. This statement will return either `None` or (I'm guessing) a list (because you use `.append()`).

With these comments, you should be able to make a piece of code that does something like (**this is pseudocode**):

```
function return_file_data(filename)
  if file_exists(filename)
   data = filename.read_all() #including gunzip
   remove(filename)

  return data or None

function process_data(data)
  users = []
  for line in data
    users.append(json.loads(line))

  return users

function main(filename)
  data = return_file_data(filename)
  if data
    users = process_data(data)
    # do something with the users data

if __name__ == "__main__":
  filename = get_filename() # I'm sure you do that somewhere?
  main(filename)
```

You'll notice I dropped the datetime comparison **AND** the get_new_user flag comparison - for reasons mentioned earlier. If you improve your code (as per codereview guidelines), create a new post (with your new code) and reference this post for historical purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The datetime comparison is not useless.  Indentation is significant in Python.  The code reads “if get_new_user then (if datetime comparison append else do nothing) else append”.   The user is not appended when get_new_user is true but the datetime check fails.  Your pseudocode rewrite removes this functionality, so is not equivalent.

Comment: Ah, apologies, it must have looked odd on my screen at the time (hence my questions if lines were missing as the formatting appeared out of whack). In that case, the line `users.append(json.loads(line))` would turn into a function where the check on the line data would take place.